# Installing the foreign_key_migrations plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I apologize if this is a dumb question but I've had a long week and this is just more than my feeble brain can handle at this point.

I'm trying to install the foreign_key_migrations plugin for Rails, which can be found here:
https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails/tree/master/foreign_key_migrations/

How do I install the plugin? The README files I read after cloning the Git repository don't seem to offer any installation instructions. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never heard of the plugin and sure looks useful. I might try it out some time. As for your question: do you mean how to get the plugin inside your /vendor/plugins folder? If so, that's quite simple:

```
script/plugin install https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails.git
```

When it's installed, you just need to add a foreign key via a migration, and the plugin does everything automatically it seems. To add the foreign keys on an existing database, just do the following:

```
script/generate foreign_key_migration
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

When using Rails 3, you should do:

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/harukizaemon/redhillonrails.git
```

But I don't know if this plugin works with Rails 3.

Comment: Hmm. For some reason, I don't even have anything called "plugin" in my `script` folder. I wonder what to do about that.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? If you're using Rails 3 you should use 'rails plugin install'.